# Magento 2 Elastic.co reindexing issue

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch

I have connected my magento 2 instance with elastic.co for elasticsearch service, the connection is successfull but upon reindexing I get the following error

> {"error":"no handler found for uri [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping?include_type_name=true] and method [PUT]"}

```
#0 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(317): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process4xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(28): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#2 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#3 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(329): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Core::proxy(Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureArray), Object(Closure))
#5 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(227): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array, Object(Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection), Object(Elasticsearch\Transport), Array)
#6 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(105): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->performRequest('PUT', '/magento2_produ...', Array, '{"document":{"p...', Array, Object(Elasticsearch\Transport))
#7 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Namespaces/AbstractNamespace.php(58): Elasticsearch\Transport->performRequest('PUT', '/magento2_produ...', Array, Array, Array)
#8 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Namespaces/IndicesNamespace.php(707): Elasticsearch\Namespaces\AbstractNamespace->performRequest(Object(Elasticsearch\Endpoints\Indices\PutMapping))
#9 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-7/Model/Client/Elasticsearch.php(356): Elasticsearch\Namespaces\IndicesNamespace->putMapping(Array)
#10 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/Elasticsearch.php(483): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->addFieldsMapping(Array, 'magento2_produc...', 'document')
#11 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/Elasticsearch.php(250): Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Elasticsearch->prepareIndex('1', 'magento2_produc...', 'product')
#12 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Indexer/IndexStructure.php(45): Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Elasticsearch->cleanIndex('1', 'product')
#13 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/IndexStructureProxy.php(44): Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Indexer\IndexStructure->delete('product', Array)
#14 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Indexer/IndexerHandler.php(123): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexStructureProxy->delete('product', Array)
#15 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(158): Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler->cleanIndex(Array)
#16 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(215): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeByDimensions(Array)
#17 [internal function]: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\{closure}()
#18 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/ProcessManager.php(75): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#19 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/ProcessManager.php(62): Magento\Indexer\Model\ProcessManager->simpleThreadExecute(Array)
#20 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(218): Magento\Indexer\Model\ProcessManager->execute(Array)
#21 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeFull()
#22 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callParent('executeFull', Array)
#23 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#24 /home/customer/www//public_html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callPlugins('executeFull', Array, Array)
#25 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(443): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->executeFull()
#26 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(259): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexAll()
#27 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Console/Command/IndexerReindexCommand.php(101): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexAll()
#28 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->___callParent('run', Array)
#31 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /home/customer/www//public_html/generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Console/Command/IndexerReindexCommand/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->___callPlugins('run', Array, Array)
#33 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /home/customer/www//public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 /home/customer/www//public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#38 {main}
```

Any Help what I could do nothing on the web helps.

Comment: The service used for elasticsearch is elastic.co

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elastic search version which was deployed on elastic.co was 8.0 which wasn't supported by Magento, After creating a new deployment with Version 7 which Magento supports the indexing and search results were successful.